# navigation bar end caps

Tags: html

I am really new to this, so please bear with me.  I am editing an existing 3dCart website and am having an issue with the navigation bar.

The bar background image is spanning 100% so my end caps are not showing up properly with transparency. I am cheating by making, what should be transparent on the end caps, the same color as the page background, but it's not right and you can see it.

What I would like to know is how do I place the end caps on the ends instead of 'on top' of the bar, so to speak.

```
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background: url(assets/templates/[template]/images/menu-bg.gif) repeat-x; color: #000; text-align: right">
            <tr>
              <td width="13"><img src="assets/templates/[template]/images/menu-l.png" width="13" height="48"></td>
```

The end cap (menu-l) is a png file with transparency but it is not working.  I was using a jpg with the transparent parts set as the home page background color, but it's a gradient and doesn't look right.

If someone can tell me how to place these caps on the ends, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a table, you should probably use divs.  With div elements, you can then use the position attribute to put the images directly where you want them.

```
#navcap1{position:absolute;left:XXpx;top:TTpx;}
#navcap2{position:absolute;right:ZZpx;top:TTpx;}
```

Or, the better way would probably be to make one div for the nav, then within the div float the end caps to the left and right.

```
<div id=nav style="background:imagex; prop2:x; prop3:x;">
   <div id=capleft style="display:block; float:left;"></div>
   <div id=capright style="display:block; float:right;"></div>
</div>
```

Or, you could just control the width of the div so you wouldn't even need end caps.

Either way, I wouldn't use a table, and would prob break out the style.